# Google maps api автозаполнение. Поиск региона

Tags: javascript, html-form

Всем доброго вечера.Пытаюсь сделать набор полей для ввода городов с автозаполнением. Нашел следующее решение :

```
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script>
  function initialize() {

    var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');

    var options = {
      types: ['(regions)'],
    };

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace(); //получаем место
      console.log(place);
      console.log(place.name);  //название места
      console.log(place.id);  //уникальный идентификатор места
    });

  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

В html:

```
<input id="searchTextField" size="50" type="text" />
```

Но здесь идет для конкретного элемента с id, а необходимо чтобы работало для нескольких инпутов с определенным классом.Как быть в таком случае?

Answer (score 1):

к великому несчастью а быть может и наоборот не во всех браузерах можно использовать document.getElementsByClassName.

использовать один айдишник для нескольких элементов тоже не есть хорошо. потому логичным решением проблемы будет пересмотреть построение формы. скорее всего вам попросту не нужно столько инпутов

Comment: Это все понятно, благодарю за ответ, но мне все же необходимо несколько полей на одной странице с автокомплитом.Может кто-нибудь еще что-нибудь предложит.Буду весьма признателен.

Answer (score 1):

Код js:

```
function initAutocomplete () {
var inputs = $('.searchTextField');
var options = {
    types: ['(regions)'],
};
$(inputs).each(function (i, element) {
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element, options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace(); //получаем место
        console.log(place);
        console.log(place.name);  //название места
        console.log(place.id);  //уникальный идентификатор места
        });
    });
}
```

В html:

```
<input class="searchTextField" size="50" type="text" />
```